# Is it necessary to repete the prepositions in coordinate sentences?

Tags: prepositions, coordinating-conjunctions

In the coordinate sentences introducted by prepositions is it necessary to repete the preposition in the second sentence? "I am happy to go to the cinema and to have a pizza" or "I am happy to go to the cinema and have a pizza"?

Comment: I don't know whether it's formally correct, but the latter is certainly idiomatically reasonable.

Comment: Note that both "I am happy to go into town and have a pizza" and "I am happy to go into town and to have a pizza" are both quite acceptable, but that the former strongly suggests that going into town is for the purpose of finding a pizza.

Comment: That is not a preposition. That is the infinitive particle. The second *to* (in "to the cinema") is a preposition. The other *tos* (in "to go" and "to have") are not.